# Example of a uniformly convergent subsequence of a sequence of function which is pointwise convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

let $ {f_n} $ be a sequence of function on any subset of $ \mathbb R $ and it converges pointwise to zero. Is it possible to get a subsequence which converges uniformly to zero? 
    Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1,&(x\ge n),\\0,&(x<n)\end{cases}$$it's clear that $f_n(x)\to0$ for every $x$ but no subsequence converges uniformly

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequnce $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of functions from $\mathbb R$ into itself defined by$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac1{(1+x^2)^n}&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$and prove that no subsequence of this sequence converges uniformly. However, $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges pointwise to the null function.

Comment: so you mean there is no possibility to get a uniformly convergent subsequence from any sequence of function which converges pointwise to zero?

Comment: Not at all. I only claimed that for the specific sequence that I defined.

Comment: Correct, however there are theorems about getting uniform convergence outside a set of small measure.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem

Answer (score 0):

A classic example is the sequence $f_n(x)=x^n, n=1,2,\dots $ on $(0,1).$

Comment: can anyone give me an easy example of a pointwise convergent sequence which has a uniformly convergent subsequenice?

Comment: @suchandaadhikari That's easy. The sequence $0,0,0,\dots$ will work.

Comment: nice one ..can you give me an example of a sequence of function which is not uniformly convergent but pointwise convergent and has a uniformly convergent subsequence please?

Comment: @suchandaadhikari   $x,0,x^2,0,x^3,0,\dots $